# How to make pararell JS API calls modifying responses simultaneously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios

I am trying to make multiple pararell api calls (a lot of them) with axios.all and I would like to add new property to the responses at the same time. I would like to add the mapped array values as a "newProperty" so the received objects would have that extra property

```
const url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'
const arr=[1,2]

const fn = async () => {
    const obj = (await axios.all(arr.map(el=>axios(url+el)))).map((item)=>item.data)
    console.log(obj)
}
fn()
```

```
{
    **"newProperty"**: 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'
const arr = [1, 2]
const urls = arr.map(postId => url + postId);

const fn1 = async () => {
    const objs = await axios.all(urls.map((endpoint) => axios(endpoint)));
    const datas = objs.map(obj => obj.data);
    const transformedDatas = datas.map(data => { data.property = "value"; return data });
    console.log(transformedDatas);
    return transformedDatas;
}

(async () => { 
    await fn1();
})();
```

just add the transformer code in your objs.map extract the data component of each response and add the property you want to add to it
also fn1 is a promise you need to await on it to let it finish.